How to create a custom drawer in flutter?
How to create a custom drawer in flutter?
This attached example was made with ionic, I would like to know if it is possible to create a custom drawer in flutter with this same behavior. The drawer being between the AppBar and TabNavigation.
I tried using a Stack but it didn't work.
There is also a diagram below

|----------------------------------------|
|    ________________________________    |
|   |            AppBar              |   |
|   |________________________________|   |
|                                        |
|    _____________________               |            
|    |                   |               |
|    |                   |               |
|    |      Drawer       |               |
|    |                   |               | 
|    |                   |               |
|    |                   |               |
|    |                   |               |
|    |                   |               |
|    |                   |               |
|    |                   |               |
|    |                   |               |
|    |                   |               |  
|    |___________________|               |
|            Bottom tabNavigation        |
|    ________________________________    |
|    |          news | home          |   | 
|    |_______________________________|   | 
|                                        |
|-----------------------------------------

[

While the drawer is connected with Scaffold's context, one of the way is separating AppBar and BottomNavigationBar from Scaffold, you can use a key to open and close the Drawer.
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  final scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        AppBar(
          leading: IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              bool isOpen = scaffoldKey.currentState?.isDrawerOpen ?? false;
              if (isOpen) {
                scaffoldKey.currentState?.closeDrawer();
              } else {
                scaffoldKey.currentState?.openDrawer();
              }
            },
            icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Scaffold(
            key: scaffoldKey,
            drawer: Drawer(),
            body: Column(),
          ),
        ),
        BottomNavigationBar(
          items: [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.abc), label: 'News'),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home), label: 'Home'),
          ],
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}

